# how to add a calculation of average as dynamic data structure in C language?

Tags: c, data-structures, dynamic

```
void calculateAverage(struct List *list) {
        int count = 0;
        int sumGerman = 0, sumEnglish = 0, sumMathematik = 0;
        double aveGerman = 0, aveEnglish = 0, aveMathematik = 0;

        // Sum grades
        while (current != NULL) {
            struct student *currentStudent = current->data;
            // Add only positive values
            if (currentStudent->german != 0 && currentStudent->english != 0 &&
            currentStudent->mathematik != 0) {
                count++;
                sumMathematik += currentStudent->mathematik;
                sumGerman += currentStudent->german;
                sumEnglish += currentStudent->english;

            }
            // Select Next Node
            currentStudent = currentStudent->next;
        }
        aveMathematik = (count > 0) ? (double) sumMathematik / count: 0;
        aveGerman = (count > 0) ? (double) sumGerman / count: 0;
        aveEnglish = (count > 0) ? (double) sumEnglish / count: 0;

        printf("Mathe: %.2f\n", aveMathematik);
        printf("Deutsch: %.2f\n", aveGerman);
        printf("Englisch: %.2f\n", aveEnglish);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the complier gives me an error: function definition is not allowed here
void calculateAverage(struct List *list) {

I tried to remove the end:
return 0;
}

but it did not work. How can I fix this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre].

Comment: On another note, `return 0;` in a function declared to not return anything?

Comment: Also, you don't need the `currentStudent->german != 0` etc. check. A value of `0` will not add anything to the total anyway. Besides, if `currentStudent->german` is zero, then you won't add anything to the English or math totals either, even if they have a non-zero value.

Comment: Guesswork: you are not terminating the function definition *above* this one, and are attempting to create a nested function definition.

Comment: Given that the error message is "function definition is not allowed **here**", you're going to need to give us some information about where "here" is.  This is one of the things that MRE will do.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in the code *before* the function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're facing issues with the placement of the function definition. The error "function definition is not allowed here" occurs when you try to define a function within another function or block of code.

Make sure that the `calculateAverage` function definition is outside of any other functions or blocks and is properly placed within the structure of your C program.

```
// Include necessary headers

// Define structures and other data types if needed

// Function declarations if needed

// Define the structure for a student
struct student {
    int german;
    int english;
    int mathematik;
    // Other fields if needed
    struct student *next; // Assuming a linked list structure
};

// Define the structure for a linked list node
struct List {
    struct student *data;
    struct List *next;
};

// Function to calculate average grades
void calculateAverage(struct List *list) {
    // Function implementation
    // ...
}

// Main function or other functions if needed

int main() {
    // Code for your main function
    // ...

    return 0;
}
```